# MAC OSX: Ruby on Rails and MongoDB Configuration

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

This may have been asked somewhere else but I either couldn't find it or the solution didn't help me.

I successfully installed Homebrew, RVM, Ruby on Rails and mongoDB.

I followed these instructions http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html when installing mongoid but when I ran

`rails g mongoid:config` it said it could not find the generator.

So I ran `rails g` and it wasn't in the list. I checked my gem.lock file and it wasn't in there either. I manually put it in there but still no results.

When I ran `bundle install` on the project it wasn't there either. I tried installing it in my main directory and in the project directory to no avail.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated as I am new to this.

EDIT: My gem.lock file:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
    activesupport (3.2.11)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.7.6)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.19)
    multi_json (1.5.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.4)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.11)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activerecord (= 3.2.11)
      activeresource (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.11)
    railties (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.5)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7)
    thor (0.17.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)
    uglifier (1.3.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 3.2.11)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

EDIT: Sorry here's my GEmfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your `Gemfile` here?

Comment: theTRON asked for Gemfile, not gem.lock. Your gem.lock (assume that you meant Gemfile.lock) is missing mongoid, so it's a good guess that your Gemfile is missing a line for mongoid or that the line has some problem. The instructions assume that you know about editing Gemfile and running "bundle install" - you should NOT edit Gemfile.lock by hand as you will loose the consistency provided by bundler.

Comment: As suspected, a gem line for mongoid is missing from your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per instructions, add

```
gem "mongoid", "~> 3.0.0"
```

to your Gemfile to use Mongoid 3, and then

```
bundle install
```

Make sure that bundle install succeeds, check Gemfile.lock for mongoid, then

```
rails g mongoid:config
```

Comment: Ah okay, I misunderstood the first line when I read it. My apologies.